# Localtunnel alternative not working

Tags: node.js, npm, localtunnel

I connect my app to [Localtunnel](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel). It was working very well until last week, but now it's not working:

[image: this error comes]

Comment: https://github.com/anderspitman/awesome-tunneling looks like a good list of alternatives. https://loophole.cloud/ and https://localhost.run/ and https://github.com/fatedier/frp were most interesting to me as alternatives to localtunnel and ngrok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
lt -h http://serverless.social -p 3000
```

This was a quick fix that I found, and it works well

```sh
lt -h http://serverless.social -p 3000 --subdomain charls
```

Will also let you have a custom subdomain name.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** Localtunnel appears to be working again. (Of course depending when you're reading this it may not be. Please use your own judgment.)

**Original answer:**

[The cloud-hosted part of Localtunnel](http://localtunnel.me/) is [currently down](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues/123#issuecomment-343933449). You'll have to wait until its maintainer brings it up again, or use another service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Some more issues tracking this:

- https://github.com/localtunnel/server/issues/40#issuecomment-344038789
- https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues/198
- https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues/199

Answer (score 2):

Try [localhost.run](https://localhost.run/) it works well and require no additional installation.

Answer (score 1):

Try **ngrok** : https://ngrok.com/

Its free and very easy to use...

For windows just extract the zip and run the exe file and type:

**ngrok http 3000**

note : 3000 or any other port number on which your local host is running on.

Answer (score 1):

Use termux
and get better result
otherwise you can do this
make javascript file

```
const localtunnel = require('localtunnel');
(async () => {
  const tunnel = await localtunnel({ port: 8000 });
  console.log(tunnel.url);  
  tunnel.on('close', () => {
  });
})();
```

Save it and run node filename.js

It should work
By the way it's not work in android cause it's comes with openurl which is not for android you have to change ta  script then ...so use this code you will get better result

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

`npx localtunnel --port PORT` and `lt --port PORT`

(with proper for me number of the port in place of "PORT")

and didn't receive a response for a long time in both attempts. I found here: [Use backup host `lt -h "http://serverless.social" -p PORT` if site is down](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues/344) info about the backup host, this works for me:

`t -h "http://serverless.social" -p PORT`